# Remove duplicate product photos

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql, product-images

I need to remove duplicate product photos after an import. Thumbnails were imported as product photos.

The thumbnail filename is based off the main images filename, so I have:

> fg60-2.jpg
>   fg60-2t.jpg

I need a query to look at each products images, and when it finds a product with images like:

> xxxx.jpg
>   xxxxt.jpg

Then the xxxxt.jpg image is removed.

Any MySQL experts have any advice? Were using Magento 1.7

Answer (score 3):

This was already taken care of with a module. Image Clean works with 1.4.2.0 on up to 1.7 and is available over on Magento Connect as a free install.

I recommend it as your issue will be an ongoing one. Magento does not remove images when product are deleted so not only do you have this import issue to contend with every time something goes akilter, but you have an ongoing and never ending disk usage bloat as Magento's less than stellar housekeeping lets it pack on the poundage in unused images from long dead and removed product.

**Note:** no affiliation with the above mentioned module. However, having tried to go the scripting route to manage images, found that this developer produced a module that works simply and efficiently. Just don't let it delete your placeholder images for **"No image found"**

Comment: That module just looks for images that are in the media folder but not assigned to a product. These images are assigned to products, so the module will do nothing for me.

Comment: Ok, you've got repeat images in the image gallery... You're right, this won't work.

Comment: The information is contained in catalog_product_entity_media_gallery and catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value as a starting point.

Comment: there is extension available for that http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/remove-duplicate-product-images.html

Comment: Keyur Shah, that looks like it would have been what we needed! Too late now, for $5 that plugin is worth it.

Comment: @PlacementEdge just found in google result thats why i placed here ,,,,in case if it helps some one

Answer (score 2):

Here is a free little script to take care of that.

http://www.aadil.co/how-to-delete-duplicate-product-images-in-magento/